# How can one determine whether another has sincerely repented?

Tags: nikah, tawba

I'm considering marrying a man, but he had sexual intercourse with a male-to-female pre-op transsexual.  He explains it to be a phase one he has "got out of his system", saying it's a curiosity and a fascination.

Islam Q&A discusses a similar situation, writing:

> It is not permissible for you to go ahead and marry him until he repents sincerely. Simply promising does not count as repentance.
>   <sub>[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/13707)</sub>

My question is:  How can one determine whether another has sincerely repented?

The recommendation in another [Islam Q&A fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/20068) is for someone who practices homosexuality to get married.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Why shouldn't it be permissible?

Comment: I read on Islamqa that it wasn't permissible for a woman to marry a man who committed such sins till he sincerely has repented. But how can one determine whether another has sincerely repented.

Comment: @III-AK-III How can I post this link on Islam Q&A ?

Comment: As @III-AK-III wrote it would be helpful if you shared the link of this fatwa with us.

Comment: @III-AKI-III https://islamqa.info/en/20068     https://islamqa.info/en/13707 This one was the one I referenced earlier I just noticed it doesn't relate to the situation I mentioned.

Comment: I edited the question to match [your question in the comments](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46806/is-it-permissible-to-marry-a-man-who-committed-a-sin-of-homosexuality#comment79591_46806) since you seem to know the answer to your original question *Is it permissible to marry a man who committed a sin of homosexuality?*  (Hearing the same answer again will probably not help you.)